# Move and replace directory in tomcat webapps

Tags: puppet

I'm using the puppet tomcat plugin to install and start tomcat. The tomcat installation comes with a console which is installed into ${tomcat_dir}/webapps/ROOT.

The ROOT-directory is special directory for deployment of application direct to the root of the web-server. I need to install my own application in the ROOT-directory.

Therefore I need to rename the ROOT-directory to console. As I understand I can copy the ROOT-directory to console and delete the ROOT-directory. However, when I install my own application into ROOT, how can I avoid it also being wiped by puppet.

Answer (score 0):

Although platform-dependant this was quite easy using a exec-statement. In lack of other solutions you'll do what you have to do to make stuff work.

```
exec { "move original ROOT to console":
    unless                      => "/usr/bin/test -d ${tomcatDir}/webapps/console",
    command                     => "/bin/mv ${tomcatDir}/webapps/ROOT ${tomcatDir}/webapps/console",
}
```

The command ensures moving the directory with the unfortunate name and the unless asserts that this is only executed once.